# Laravel return latest histories from all users

Tags: php, laravel

I have login history table where i save each user login/logout, therefore each user can have many rows.

I am trying to make filter to get last row of each user at once (getting latest row of all users) but not sure how to.

## Code

`controller`

```
$histories = LoginHistory::with(['user','user.roles' => function($q) {
  return $q->latest()->first();
}])->get();
```

> this return all rows from all users instead of only latest rows.

## screenshot

`table`
[image: one]

In this case my function should return 3 results as my user with id 1 has 2 rows (i only need to get latest one `row 2` ) but yet i get all 4 rows with my function.

Any idea?

Comment: did u want to get the last login user?

Comment: Downvoter care to tell what's wrong with the question?

Answer (score 0):

The raw MySQL query you might use here would look something like this:

```
SELECT lh1.*
FROM login_history lh1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, MAX(login) AS max_login
    FROM login_history
    GROUP BY user_id
) lh2
    ON lh1.user_id = lh2.user_id AND lh1.login = lh2.max_login
```

Your updated Laravel/Eloquent code:

```
$subquery = DB::table('login_history')
    ->select(DB::raw("user_id, MAX(login) AS max_login"))
    ->groupBy('user_id');

$rs = LoginHistory::joinSub($subquery, 'lh2', function($join) {
    $join->on('login_history.user_id', '=', 'lh2.user_id');
    $join->on('login_history.login', '=', 'lh2.max_login');
})
    ->select(['login_history.*'])
    ->get();
```